# How to create a vertical kendo ui tabstrip?

Tags: html, kendo-tabstrip

```
    <kendo-tabstrip>
       <ul>
          <li class="k-state-active">TAB1</li>
          <li>TAB2</li>
       </ul>
       <div>
          <h2>TAB1 description</h2>
       </div>
        <div>
          <h2>TAB2 description</h2>
       </div>
    </kendo-tabstrip>
```

Is there a way to create a vertical kendo tabstrip by adding a html attribute to  tag? I looked in to [this](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/tab-position). But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this example tutorial for vertical tabs http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/tab-position